# How to put user inputs into an array and find the median in VBasic

Tags: vb.net

So i'm coding an application that takes the inputs from a user through a input box, and displays their numbers in a listbox. At the same time, the user's input is thrown into an array, which I have no clue how to do. This is what I have so far.

The Following is the code for the users input.

```
Dim blnisvalid As Boolean
    Dim intArrayLength, intNumber As Integer
    intArrayLength += 1
    Dim arrNumbers(intArrayLength) As Integer
    Array.Sort(arrNumbers)
    For IntI As Integer = 1 To arrNumbers.GetUpperBound(0)
        blnisvalid = Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Please enter a number"), intNumber)
        If blnisvalid = False OrElse intNumber <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value")
        ElseIf blnisvalid = True Then
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intNumber)
        End If


    Next
```

This is the code that takes the array, determines if it's even or odd numbers, and finds the median. For some reason, it's showing me a 'null' error because I put declared the array as a private so i can use it in both.

```
    Array.Sort(arrNumbers)
    If arrNumbers.Length Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Median =" & arrNumbers(arrNumbers.GetUpperBound(0) \ 2).ToString)
    Else
        Dim intNum1 As Integer = arrNumbers(arrNumbers.Length \ 2)
        Dim intNum2 As Integer = arrNumbers((arrNumbers.Length \ 2) - 1)
        Dim intMedian As Integer = (intNum1 + intNum2) \ 2
        MessageBox.Show("Median =" & intMedian.ToString)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you declared the in one Sub and are then using it in another. Only because a variable has the same name they are not pointing to the same value all the time.

Variables go "out of scope" if the block you declared them in ends. This can be for example a loop somewhere in your method but also the method itself. So in your case the user inputs are gone after they finish typing them in.

You have more then one way to solve this. Since you are storing the values in a listbox you can take the values from there in your median method.

```
Dim arrNumbers(lstNumbers.items. Count) as 
For i = 0 to  lstNumbers.items.count - 1 
  ArrNumbers(i)  = CInt(lstNumbers.items(i))
Next
'calculate median
```

You can also declare arrNumbers as a global variable instead by moving the statement outside of the sub. But make sure to set the array bounds with the redim command before storing values in it.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private arrNumbers() as Integer
  Private Sub GetInput()
    Redim arrNumbers(intArrayLength-1) as Integer '-1 because you are declaring the upper boundary, not the length, so (1) would mean two values in the array
    'Get user input
  End Sub
  Private Sub GetMedian()
    If IsNothing(arrNumbers) Then Exit Sub 'Check this to prevent a Null-Exception
    'Calculate the median
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an ideal Function in VB.NET to find the Median of any Array (type Double can be changed to your Array's type):

```
Public Function Median(ByVal YourArray As Double()) As Double
        Dim size As Integer = YourArray.Length
        If size = 0 Then Return 0
        If size Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Return (YourArray(CInt(size / 2) - 1) + YourArray(CInt(size / 2))) / 2
        Else
            Return YourArray(CInt(Math.Floor(size / 2)))
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `arrNumbers.Average()`

Comment: Average is not the median. Also if he is getting a nullreference exception the array would also be nothing for .Average